# NodeJs sequelize get date between data's

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

This question is already asked but that not solve my issue.

I have two fields in my `database` those are `fromDate` & `toDate`. I want to validate `fromDate` & `toDate` while insert new data.

I mean, I already have **fromDate** = **2019-04-20** and **toDate** = **2019-04-30** in my `database`.

Now am trying to insert **`fromDate`** as **`2019-04-25`** and **`toDate`** as **`2019-04-26`**.

In this case throw error like **You have already this date's...!**

This is my code:

`controller.js`

```
const db = require('../../config/database');
const CubbersClosure = require('../../model/cubber/cubbersClosure.model')(db.sequelize, db.Sequelize);

exports.cubbersAddClosure = (req, res) =>{
   CubbersClosure.create({
        cubbersId:req.body.cubbersId,
        userId:req.body.userId,
        fromDate:req.body.fromDate,
        toDate:req.body.toDate,
        status:1,
        createdBy:req.body.createdBy,
        updatedBy:req.body.updatedBy
    }).then(closure=>{
        res.status(200).send({status: 'success', resCode:200, msg:'Shop closure date added successfully...!', data:closure});
    }).catch(function (error) {
        res.status(403).send({status: 'error', resCode:200, msg:'Internal Server Error...!', data:error});
    });
}
```

`model.js`

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize)=>{
    const cubbersAvailability = sequelize.define('cubbersclosure',{
        closureId:{
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey:true,
            autoIncrement:true
        },
        cubbersId:{type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
        userId:{type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
        fromDate:{type: Sequelize.STRING},
        toDate:{type: Sequelize.STRING},
        status:{type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
        createdAt:{type: Sequelize.DATE},
        createdBy:{type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
        updatedAt:{type: Sequelize.DATE},
        updatedBy:{type: Sequelize.INTEGER},
    },
    {
        freezeTableName: true
    });
    return cubbersAvailability;
}
```

Database:
[image]

> Note: Before insert new date i want to validate this between date is already exits or not...!

Comment: If you only need this logic in this controller, you can `findOne` with the proper between/overlapping logic you need and check you had no results before inserting the new item. If you want this logic to be broader, you can probably sort this out with [hooks](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/hooks.html) like `beforeSave`.